# Combining words

Tags: meaning

Well i wanted to know if combining finnish word "Erakko" and japanese word "Hikikomori" into "Erakomori" would mean something stupid or could actually be used...?

I mean, hikikomori is kind of its own word without direct english translation right?

Comment: @naruto just need to know if it means something silly because isn't era and komori also standalone words? I wonder what japanese person would think of the word erakomori... but i guess they wouldn't be able to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hikikomori (引きこもり) is a pure Japanese-origin word. It's a stem (masu-stem) of a compound verb 引きこもる, which means "to lock oneself up", "to confine oneself". I know [this word has gained popularity outside of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikikomori), but I have no idea how it's used in Western countries. Etymologically, it has nothing to do with hermits, of course.

Erakomori absolutely makes no sense to ordinary Japanese speakers because they don't know *Erakko* in the first place. Well, people sometimes do coin mixed-English-Japanese-compound words, but this one is simply too difficult. I don't know if it makes sense to Finnish people. If you believe both Erakko and hikikomori are well-recognized words in your target community and everyone can guess what Erakomori means, go ahead.

Or you're worried about whether erakomori happens to sound like something totally different and funny (["Kinky" university](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindai_University), for example)? Then don't worry, erakomori sounds like meaningless gibberish to me. [えら (*era*)](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%B0%93) in Japanese also means *gills* (of fish), but I think very few Japanese people would have it in mind when they suddenly see "erakomori".

Comment: Thanks for very comprehensive answer, just what i wanted to hear! Hikikomori not having anything to do with hermits is ok, i am combining the two and so some finnish people may understand the word "Erakomori". Kinky university huh... interesting.

Comment: The may be a danger for the word to be misspelled as エロ子守 ;).  (@Yoru this is "ero" (from erotic) + "komori" (babysitter)).

Comment: @kroki well im not gonna misspell it :D as for komori era should make it sound different enough...

Comment: Yoru, if you accept this as your answer, please push the button to acknowledge it